# Dynamic Query not return Data using multiple select filter

Tags: php

I have problem with my query's.
I have a form Search with multiple types of Selections Values.Some Filters are single select and some of them are multiple selection values(mandatory).
My problem are when i have Multiple Selection and need to use in my query clause`WHERE` with `LIKE  AND OR`.

I Build my result page using dynamic query PDO and `WHERE` clause are implode and connect with`AND`, but i don't know how to add `OR`, because is not mandatory for use multiple selections.
My code on Result.php are:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $conditions = [];
    $parameters = [];



    if (isset($_POST["reg"])) {

        $conditions[] = 'region = ? ';
        $parameters[] = isset($_POST['reg']) ? $_POST['reg'] : '' ;

    }

    if(isset($_POST["paravilw"])) {

        $conditions[] = 'stt_rsw = ? ';
        $parameters[] = isset($_POST['paravilw']) ? $_POST['paravilw'] : '' ;

    }


    if (isset($_POST["pros_tre"])) {
        $prev_table ='" OR pros_tresit LIKE "'; 

        $value_rank = $_POST["pros_tre"];
        $value_rank_implode = "" . implode("%" .$prev_table."%", $_POST['pros_tre']) .""; - ---i tried to use implode but is not return if i have multi selection
        $value_rank_explode = explode('|', $value_rank_implode);


        $conditions[] = ' pros_tresit LIKE ? ';
        $parameters[] = '%'.$value_rank_implode.'%';

        //$parameters[] =  '%' . implode("%' or pros_tresit like '%", $_POST['pros_tre']) .'%';


        var_dump($parameters);
        //print_r($parameters);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM import ";

    if ($conditions)
    {
        $sql .= " WHERE " .implode(" AND  ", $conditions);

    }



    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $total_row = $stmt->rowCount();
    $output = '';

  }
```

Now i will explain what i tried to do. I use implode method for add `OR pros_tresit LIKE` Manually on every new value selected.

```
$prev_table ='" OR pros_tresit LIKE "'; 
        $value_rank_implode = "" . implode("%" .$prev_table."%", $_POST['pros_tre']) .""; - ---i tried to use implode but is not return if i have multi selection
```

But is not return data  my `var_dump($sql)` result are

```
SELECT * FROM import WHERE region = ? AND stt_rsw= ? AND pros_tresit LIKE ?
```

and my `var_dump($parameters);` are:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "NOS" [1]=> string(4) "TRUS" [2]=> string(43) "%Sil%" OR pros_tresit LIKE "%Unr%"
```

if copy paste last array[2] and run manualy in my databse it works  and return data
become it comes like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM import WHERE region = 'NOS' AND stt_rsw = 'TRUS' AND pros_tresit  LIKE  "%Sil%" OR pros_tresit  LIKE "%Unr%"
```

I don't know how to fix this problem with multi selection `OR table_name LIKE`
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i found a method who work but is not what i expected to do so

1. i comment all code from

```
 if (isset($_POST["pros_tre"])) {
        $prev_table ='" OR pros_tresit LIKE "'; 

        $value_rank = $_POST["pros_tre"];
        $value_rank_implode = "" . implode("%" .$prev_table."%", $_POST['pros_tre']) .""; - ---i tried to use implode but is not return if i have multi selection
        $value_rank_explode = explode('|', $value_rank_implode);


        $conditions[] = ' pros_tresit LIKE ? ';
        $parameters[] = '%'.$value_rank_implode.'%';

        //$parameters[] =  '%' . implode("%' or pros_tresit like '%", $_POST['pros_tre']) .'%';


        var_dump($parameters);
        //print_r($parameters);
    }
```

AND i make something like here the rest of code works very good with all conditions

```
    if ($_POST["pros_tre"] && $conditions){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM import ";

        $sql .= " WHERE " .implode(" AND  ", $conditions);

        $sql .= " AND pros_tresit LIKE  '%" . implode("%' or pros_tresit like '%", $_POST['pros_tre']) ."%'";
    }
```

I want to thanks to  'noahheck'  from GitHub because i install on my Project

[E_PDOStatement](https://github.com/noahheck/E_PDOStatement)

Is very helpful when you have alot of query and need to see how data it comes in SQL.
For example this functions help me to debug my query statements .

I know this is not the perfectly resolve but for moment it works maybe in couple weeks or months after i will get more knowledge on PHP i will figure out how to do it.

Thanks stackoverflow